# How find this diophantine equation $(3x-1)^2+2=(2y^2-4y)^2+y(2y-1)^2-6y$ integer solution

Tags: diophantine-equations

Find this following  Diophantine equation all integer solution
$$(3x-1)^2+2=(2y^2-4y)^2+y(2y-1)^2-6y$$
or
$$9x^2-6x+3=4y^4-12y^3+12y^2-5y$$
Maybe this equation can be solved by using Pell equation methods?

I want take right is Quadratic formula with $(ay^2+by+c)$

maybe we have
$$(3x-1)^2-A(ay^2+by+c)^2=B?$$

[image]

Comment: Where does this come from? Do you have some reason to believe that it's possible to solve it?

Comment: It is come from china BBS student ask it.maybe is come from Mathematical olympiad  problem adaptation(改编)

Comment: So you don't really know whether it is solvable, or whether there is an elementary approach.

Comment: x=1, y=2 is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as
$$(3x-1)^2-(2y^2-3y+\tfrac34)^2=-\tfrac12y-\tfrac{41}{16}.$$
Factoring the LHS gives two factors at least one of which gets too large as $y$ is large, as
$$|(3x-1)-(2y^2-3y+\tfrac34)|+|(3x-1)+(2y^2-3y+\tfrac34)|\geqslant2\cdot|2y^2-3y+\tfrac34|.$$
It suffices to check the $y$'s with $-\tfrac12y-\tfrac{41}{16}=0$ (impossible) or $|-\tfrac12y-\tfrac{41}{16}|\geqslant|2y^2-3y+\tfrac34|$, that is, $y\in\{0,1,2\}$.
(Note all this makes a little more sense after denominators are cleared, but it's perfectly valid to act as if they are.)
The only solution is $(1,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the quadratic formula. Solve for $x$ and you get the form,

$$x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{f(y)}}{2a}$$

hence you must find integer $y$ such that,

$$f(y) = z^2$$

If your $f(y)$ is a polynomial ***only*** of degree $n=2$, then generally you can use a *Pell equation* to find an infinite more integer $y$.

Unfortunately, your $f(y)$ has degree $n>2$ (namely $n=4$), and after some transformations this is an *elliptic curve*. And it is well-known an elliptic curve only has a finite number of integer solutions.